# Lightweight hash function

Tags: one-way-function

I am researching about lightweight hash functions and I've got two related questions:

1. What is the standard or requirement for a hash function in general to be considered lightweight ?
2. Why can it be said that the PHOTON hash function is lightweight?

Comment: Hi sofu and welcome. I've formatted and reordered your questions. I've put the generic question first if you don't mind. If you want to make yourself known here, please put the personal details into your profile instead of the question. Questions should contain the minimum amount of information required to answer them (conciseness).

Comment: A quick look at some results I think "lightweight" is more a design goal than a formally stated requirement for hash functions. PHOTON with an output of 256 bits for may score worse than Keccak / 256 bits (another sponge based hash that won the SHA-3 contest) for some specific runtimes (e.g. ATtiny devices). Usually lightweight means a good mix of code size, RAM and performance requirements. (I'm typing an answer again, aren't I?)

Comment: Yes you are. To be honest, the question is quite on the edge to be off-topic (reference recommendation), as it is missing any information about research done, an actual non-general question, etc.